# Modular usage of Firebase v9 Beta Library

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Other important information:

1. Project uses React Library
2. Initialized with Create React App

This is how my code typically looks like on v8:

```
// firebase.js

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

export const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const firestore = app.firestore();
```

```
// app.js
import { firestore } from './firebase'

firestore.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    });
});
```

I believe with v9, Firebase no longer has that side effect import problem, and so now we explicitly state what functions we want from a package.

```
// firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

export const app = initializeApp(config)
export const firestore = getFirestore()
```

Code below is from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#read_data)

```
// app.js
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore"; 

try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    first: "Alan",
    middle: "Mathison",
    last: "Turing",
    born: 1912
  });

  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

Will the code above (which uses the `addDoc` and `collection` imports) refer to the initialized Firestore instance in `firebase.js`, or is there a proper way to use the initialized Firestore instance?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore instances are managed from the core Firebase App, the firestore modules only include the libraries to make the requests. The solution to getting the Firestore instance without having to reference the core app is to request the instance from the Firestore modules.

```js
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const db = getFirestore();
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize